# Plot sphere with Julia and PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia

Recently I tried to plot a sphere using PyPlot/Julia and unfortunately it was harder than I thought.
Probably there's something wrong with points generation, but I can't figure out why my implementation didn't work. Although everything is fine with original python code.

I've tried to adapt [demo2](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) from matplotlib surface plot doc as MWE:

```
using PyPlot
u = linspace(0,2*π,100);
v = linspace(0,π,100);

x = cos(u).*sin(v);
y = sin(u).*sin(v);
z = cos(v);

surf(x,y,z)
```

And I'm getting [image: this] instead of [image: the right one.]

So, what's exactly wrong in my Julia implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that is not your typo not defining `y`?

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. Of course it'is typo. Otherwise it fails with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This no longer works in Julia 1.1.2 to draw the sphere. Use this instead

```
using PyPlot
n = 100
u = range(0,stop=2*π,length=n);
v = range(0,stop=π,length=n);

x = cos.(u) * sin.(v)';
y = sin.(u) * sin.(v)';
z = ones(n) * cos.(v)';

# The rstride and cstride arguments default to 10
surf(x,y,z, rstride=4, cstride=4)
```

Answer (score 9):

`x`, `y` and `z` should be matrices, not vectors -- otherwise you only have a curve drawn on the sphere, instead of the surface itself.

```
using PyPlot
n = 100
u = linspace(0,2*π,n);
v = linspace(0,π,n);

x = cos(u) * sin(v)';
y = sin(u) * sin(v)';
z = ones(n) * cos(v)';

# The rstride and cstride arguments default to 10
surf(x,y,z, rstride=4, cstride=4)
```

The curve initially drawn corresponds to the diagonal of those matrices.

```
plot( diag(x), diag(y), diag(z), color="yellow", linewidth=3 )
```

[image: Sphere+curve]

Comment: The first diagram above is NOT a curve drawn on the sphere - it has straight cylindrical not spherical components.

Comment: @javadba You can check that they are indeed on the sphere by computing the (squared) distance to the origin,
`x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2`: it is 1 for all the points.
What may be confusing is the way Matplotlib tries to draw this curve as a surface, using segments linking each point to the first.